# Watchface companion app not appearing

Tags: java, android, watchface

**Problem:** Im trying to add a companion app to my watchface, I thought it would be simple as it wasn't to difficult to add the configuration for android wear. But i cant seem to get the gear to show in the ***android wear app*** so i can open the companion configuration app. No matter what I do.

Ive spent a while trying to solve this and i really don't know what Im doing wrong, Ive installed the google examples and they show the settings. Can anyone else see what on earth in doing wrong?

> XML MANIFEST FOR COMPANION APP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="archtectsproductions.linuxwatchface">
<!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<!-- All intent-filters for config actions must include the categories
    com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION and
    android.intent.category.DEFAULT. -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MobileConfig"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="archtectsproductions.linuxwatchface.CONFIG_DIGITAL" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

> GRADEL FOR MOBILE APP

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "archtectsproductions.watchfacelinuxterminal"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 23
        versionName "7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.1.0'
    wearApp project(':wear')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.8.0'
}
```

> JAVA FOR MOBILE CONFIG

```
package archtectsproductions.linuxwatchface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import android.support.wearable.companion.WatchFaceCompanion;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class MobileConfig extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String mPeerId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mobileconfiglayout);
        mPeerId = getIntent().getStringExtra(WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_PEER_ID);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

        ComponentName name =
                getIntent().getParcelableExtra(WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_WATCH_FACE_COMPONENT);
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(label.getText() + " (" + name.getClassName() + ")");

            }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

}
```

I really can't see what Im doing wrong? The Little gear doesn't appear over the top of the icon in the android wear app. BUT it works for the google examples. Ive copied manifests over. Can anyone else see what i might be doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Solved my problem, I'm basically an idiot who doesn't read documentation properly. I had to include

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionConfigurationAction"
            android:value="com.FOOBAR.android.FOOBAR.watchface.CONFIG_HANDHELD" />
```

In my wear manifest. Everything is fine now.
So if anyone else has this problem that's the solution.